# Laravel hasManyThrough return nothing

Tags: php, laravel

**Products:**

```
-----------------------
|id | name  | seller_id  |
-----------------------
| 1 | bmw   |    1     |
-----------------------
| 2 | benz  |    1     |
-----------------------
| 2 | reno  |    2     |
-----------------------
```

**Buy:**

```
------------------------------
|id | product_id  | buyer_id  |
------------------------------
| 1 |     1     |      1      |
------------------------------
| 2 |     1     |      2      |
------------------------------
| 3 |     2     |      22     |
------------------------------
```

**Buyer:**

```
------------------------------
|id | name     |       email  |
------------------------------
| 1 |     john     |      @   |
------------------------------
| 2 |     mike     |      @   |
------------------------------
| 3 |     dave     |      @  |
------------------------------
```

**Explaination:**

Seller `products` store in `products` table, after buyer bought products, it store in `buy` table. there are `buyer` table and also `seller` table, what I want to do is, show those `buyer` data to `seller` who has bought seller products.

Consider, a seller with `seller_id` 1, made products, some buyers bought his/her products, right? now I want to show to seller, who bought your products. john and mike bought bmw, now seller with id 1 should see mike and john email and etc under each products.

**What I tried:**

*ProductController.php:*

```
$pro = Product::where('seller_id', $seller->id)->where('deleted', 0)->with('buyer')->get();
```

*Product.php:*

```
function buyer()
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\Buy', 'id'); // this just show me buyer_id
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Buyer', 'App\Buy', 'id', 'id', 'product_id', 'buyer_id');
    }
```

This return me products but `buyer` is empty `"buyer": []`, I'm new to laravel, I don't know which `localKey`, `firstKey`, `secondKey` or `secondLocalKey` related to which table. So any idea what I have done wrong?

**-- Edit --**

```
public function userproducts()
{
    $seller = Auth::seller();
    $pro = Product::where('seller_id', $seller->id)->where('deleted', 0)->with('buyer')->get();

    return response()->json($pro, 200 );
}
```

Comment: change `product.php buyer` to this one and let me know the result: `public function buyers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Buy', 'App\Buyer');
    }`

Comment: @Hamid `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`

Comment: Why downvotes? Please provide comments so that OP may able to edit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the wrong relationship. As you explain your Product has many buyers and the buyer can purchase many Products.

So, It'll be a Many-to-Many Relationship.

Try to make relationship as below and then check it'll work for you.

**Product.php** Model

```
function buyers(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Buyer','Buy_table_name','product_id','buyer_id');
}
```

In **Buyer.php** Model

```
function products(){   
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','Buy_table_name','buyer_id','product_id');
}
```

Now, use this query in controller file.

```
$pro = Product::where('seller_id', $seller->id)->where('deleted', 0)->with('buyers')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but still `"buyer": []`

Comment: What is `agents` I think it should be `buyers`?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is the real name, yes, that means buyers

Comment: Can you show model code so that I can find out where did you make the mistake? You can edit the question. One more thing what is `$seller->id` contain?

Comment: Added to question. $seller->id return seller id, contain an id (int)

Comment: Have you changed the relationships in models? In Product model and Buyer model? It'll be `belongsToMany`

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I double check again, but I'm sure everything is based on your answer.

Comment: Oh, I see where did I mistake. Actually, I placed the wrong params. Please check the edited answer and then check.